# Do I need a primary key if my composite index is unique?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, innodb

Do I need a primary key if my composite index is unique? Shall I then assign my composite index as primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on situations.

Generally a primary key always create a clustered index on the table.

Other keys like Unique key and Composite Indexes creates non-clustered index on the table.

You can assign composite index as primary key as long as they form unique identity for the row in the table.

It is recommended to use numeric single field based  primary key in web applications for better performance in Application layer.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can assign index as primary key.
but it depends upon your need.